# JavaScript: var NumberTable definition and coding

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to define a number for a form. I was researching a bit and mixed this together (here the first line):

```
 var NumberTable

    [

        { valid: true, minNumber: 0, maxNumber: 4, factor: 0.0, label: 'Level 1' }

    ];
```

I was just wondering, what is the "factor" for? And I am using these brackets "[ ]", does it mean I am using arrays?

I was using one the brackets "{ }" before and someone told me this is not even JavaScript. Didn't know what to responsd to this but I was hoping if you could confirm me if I am right (that this is actually used in JavaScript).

Comment: You sure that's the code? Is it missing a `=` somewhere?

Comment: [Best resources to learn Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript)

Comment: You 'mixed this together'? If *you* put it together why are you asking *us* what the 'factor' is for?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning that stuff to the actual variable, so I'm going to assume you meant this.

```
var NumberTable = [
  { valid: true, minNumber: 0, maxNumber: 4, factor: 0.0, label: 'Level 1' }
];
```

> what is the "factor" for?

No idea. It's a property of an object. You haven't pasted enough code to know how it's used. It's nothing magic or special. This object simply has a property named `factor` which has a value of `0`.

> And I am using these brackets "[ ]", does it mean I am using arrays?

Yes. You appear to be assigning an array with one element in it to `NumberTable`.

> I was using one the brackets "{ }" before and someone told me this is not even JavaScript. Didn't know what to responsd to this but I was hoping if you could confirm me if I am right (that this is actually used in JavaScript).

`{}` are used for a few things in JavaScript. In this case you are creating an Object literal.  An object is a dictionary of key/value pairs. You are creating this within `[]` which denotes an array literal. So you end up with an array with a single object in it.